# PHP check if $_POST equals a specific value

Tags: php, validation, if-statement

I am trying to get PHP `$_POST` to show if its equaled or not from a form selection.
I have searched/tried different things but can seem to make it work.

Form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="sig_action.php" method="post">
    Phone Lines:<br />
    <select name="phone_op_1">
        <option value="T ">T: Office Phone</option>
        <option value="F ">F: Office Fax</option>
        <option value="TF ">TF: Toll Free Office Phone</option>
        <option value="C ">C: Cell Phone</option>
        <option value="none">none</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Form Handler:

```
<html>
    <?php
        if ($_POST['phone_op_1'] == 'none') {
        echo 'found none';
        } else {
        echo 'not found none';
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: print `$_POST['phone_op_1']` see it's value.learn to debug your code

Comment: **HOW** does this not work?

Comment: Why don't you print_r() or var_dump() the $_POST ?

Comment: `var_export($_POST);` could also be used to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should be:

```
<html>
    <?php
        if ($_POST['phone_op_1'] == 'none' || empty($_POST['phone_op_1'])) {
        echo 'found none';
        } else {
        echo 'not found none';
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

and:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="sig_action.php" method="post">
    Phone Lines:<br />
    <select name="phone_op_1">
        <option value="none" selected>none</option>
        <option value="T ">T: Office Phone</option>
        <option value="F ">F: Office Fax</option>
        <option value="TF ">TF: Toll Free Office Phone</option>
        <option value="C ">C: Cell Phone</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If nothing is selected, then the value will not be set. Additionally, if you don't want them to be able to reselect the "none" option, then also add the [disabled attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp).

---

#### Side Note:

While there is technically nothing wrong with checking the value like this in PHP, it can be considered bad practice. A good practice would be to have an array of all the possible values for this option and then check if `$_POST['phone_op_1']` existed in that array with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Then, if it does not exist in that array, assume the value is "none"

Example:

```
$my_array = array(
    'T ',
    'F ',
    'TF ',
    'C '
);

$result = 'none';
if (in_array(strtoupper($_POST['phone_op_1']), $my_array)) {
    $output = strtoupper($_POST['phone_op_1']);
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick-J it worked great. And i agree the array might be a better idea here.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the $_POST is empty, if you specify that none is selected then it'll have 'none' in the variable

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="sig_action.php" method="post">
Phone Lines:<br />
<select name="phone_op_1">
    <option value="T ">T: Office Phone</option>
    <option value="F ">F: Office Fax</option>
    <option value="TF ">TF: Toll Free Office Phone</option>
    <option value="C ">C: Cell Phone</option>
    <option selected value="none">none</option>
</select><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['phone_op_1']))
{
    // To determine if the var has a value
    // you can handle an error here
}
else
{
    // Do you logic here
}
```

Or try debugging printing the value like this:

```
print_r($_POST);
die();
```